# Haskell: How to use let-in construction?

Tags: haskell

I wrote a `sort` function. It's pretty weird.

```
sort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort xs = repeat'' sort' (xs) (length xs) 

repeat'' f xs 0 = xs
repeat'' f xs n = repeat'' f (f xs) (n-1)

sort' (x:y:xs)
        | x < y     = y : sort' (x:xs)
        | otherwise = x : sort' (y:xs)
sort' x = x
```

How can I prettify it using `let-in` construction?

I think my try doesn't look good:

```
sort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort xs = let 
             r f xs 0 = xs
             r f xs n = r f (f xs) (n-1)
          in r f' xs $ length xs where
               f' (x:y:xs) | x < y     = y : f' (x:xs) 
                           | otherwise = x : f' (y:xs)
               f' a = a
```

Comment: It might be better to use the `where` construction for cases like this.  `where` lets you declare your external function first, while defining your helper functions in a local scope which doesn't clutter your root namespace.

Comment: a `let` expression can contain more than one definition, as long as they all start at the same indentation. in your case, `f'` can go under `r`. then `r` simplifies to `sort xs = iterate f' xs !! length xs where f' (x:y:xs) ...`...

Comment: This looks like some sort of bubble sort with a fixed number of passes. In Haskell, it's usually better to write a merge sort if you want something simple, and it's efficient to boot.

Comment: Why do you think it would be better to have everything in a single function using `let` (or `where`)? I think your first try is much clearer and I don't see why grouping everything together would help .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really suited to the codereview stackexchange site.

Comment: @sclv this would not be off-topic for Stack Overflow _per se_ as it is about a specific programming question ("How can I prettify it using let-in construction?"). That being said, it could be a good fit for Code Review, should the author desire improvements on all aspects of the code.

Comment: Phrancis: but there already _is_ a let-in construction given, just one considered insufficiently pretty.